# Как поменять значение свойства класса только для 2 тега div с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть html код:

```html
<div class="fruits">
<p>1</p>
<div>
<div class="fruits">
<p>2</p>
<div>
<div class="fruits">
<p>3</p>
<div>
```

И есть css код:

```css
.myfruits {
margin: 20px;
}
```

Как поменять значение свойства margin класса .myfruits только для 2 diva с помощью js?

Comment: А через CSS почему нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

Странно, в HTML `fruits`,а в CSS `myfruits`
Добраться до второго элемента класса `myfruits` можно как-то так

```
var e2 = document.getElementsByClassName("myfruits")[1];
```

До свойства margin

```
e2.style.margin
```

Answer (score 0):

На JS отвечает прошлый ответ. Я предлагаю решение на CSS:

```css
.fruits:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruits">
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="fruits">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="fruits">
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery - `$("div:nth-of-type(2)").css("margin", "20px")`

Comment: А как же `.eq(1)`?

Comment: @Yuri я написал так поскольку 2-й скрываем и 2-йка в дужках. Чтобы не порождать здесь множество а почему.